# CakePHP Auth Component: How do I check if someone is logged in?

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I'm using the auth component and I don't want the login page to be accessible once the user has logged in, it should only be accessed by anonymous users. What can I put in my login method to accomplish this? I've tried this:

```
if (isset($this->Auth->user('id')) {
    $this->redirect('/profile/');
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Can't use method return value

Comment: For future reference, the main error here is due to the use of `isset()` on something that isn't a variable.  Also, there's a missing end parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($this->Session->check('Auth.User')){
    $this->redirect('/profile/');
}
```

Comment: Do you know how you would do this within the view files? So that I may determine whether a login/logout link should be presented?

Comment: @alvincrespo, you can use [`AuthComponent::user()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent::user) or [`CakeSession::read()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html#CakeSession::read).

Answer (score 11):

The Auth Component actually provides [a method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent::loggedIn) for checking if the user is logged in.

```
$this->Auth->loggedIn();
```

There are a half dozen other ways to check, but this one is best because it abstracts away the implementation of the authentication session.   Also, it's easier to read.